# Undisplayed countries in Plotly shift event_data return (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to determine clicked country in a world map displayed in shiny.

I used [this example for click event](https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-map-click/) and [this one for display](https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/) and this code works:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(countrycode)

df <- countrycode_data[,c("iso3c", "country.name")]
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
df$random <- rnorm(dim(df)[1])

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot"), textOutput("text"))), 

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$text <- renderPrint({
      d <- event_data("plotly_click")
      ifelse( is.null(d), 
              "No selection", 
              as.character(df[as.numeric(d[2])+1,"country.name"])) 
      })

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(df, z=~random, locations=~iso3c, 
                                    text=~country.name, type="choropleth")})
  }))
```

When I click on **Afghanistan** which is the first country of the dataset, it correctly selects it

But if I click on **Albania** which is the third one, it returns **Aland Islands** which is the second, and which is not displayed by Plotly.

So I'm guessing that the selection is calculated on a list of displayed entries which I project on the original dataset (which includes all countries)

I unsuccessfully tried to find on github the country list used by Plotly, which I could use to remove unknown countries and fix the shift.

Comment: [countrycode](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode) is pretty nice.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire but it also contains American Samoa(ASM)
and Andorra(AND)

Comment: Which it handles fine.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is to use a country list like the one included in package `countrycode` and plot it, then remove each country that is not (currently) handled by `plotly`. This gave me this list of ISO codes to remove:

```
CountriesNotInPlotly <- structure(list(
iso3c = c("ALA", "ASM", "AND", "AIA", "ATA", "ATG", 
"ABW", "BHR", "BRB", "BMU", "BES", "BIH", "BVT", "IOT", "CPV", 
"CYM", "CAF", "CXR", "CCK", "COM", "COD", "COG", "COK", "CUW", 
"CSK", "DMA", "FLK", "FRO", "GUF", "PYF", "DDR", "GIB", "GRD", 
"GLP", "GUM", "GGY", "HMD", "VAT", "HKG", "IMN", "JEY", "KIR", 
"LIE", "MAC", "MDV", "MLT", "MHL", "MTQ", "MUS", "MYT", "FSM", 
"MCO", "MSR", "NRU", "ANT", "NIU", "NFK", "MNP", "PLW", "PCN", 
"REU", "BLM", "SHN", "KNA", "LCA", "MAF", "SPM", "VCT", "WSM", 
"SMR", "STP", "SYC", "SGP", "SXM", "SGS", "SJM", "TKL", "TON", 
"TTO", "TCA", "TUV", "UMI", "VGB", "VIR", "WLF", "YMD", "YUG", 
"EAZ")), .Names = "iso3c", row.names = c(NA, -88L), class = "data.frame")
```